# Maven shade plugin ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, maven-shade-plugin

I'm trying to use the maven shade plugin.

I'm using: Java 7, Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.3.9Final, maven-shade plugin version 2.3

I have the following error. Can't figure out the problem.

```
    BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [other/project/persistence/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryProvider.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type java.time.LocalTime not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1052)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:227)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.getMetamodels(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type java.time.LocalTime not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.extractAttributeConverterParameterizedType(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.<init>(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Configuration.java:2729)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Configuration.java:2673)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildHibernateConfiguration(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
]       
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.LocalTime
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
]
```

**EDIT**:
Found the problem, but still not the solution: I'm using LocalDate from org.threeten.threetenbp and I have set the jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true. As I said, works ok when running the main class from IntelliJ but not when executing the jar.

Comment: Did you specify source and target in maven compiler configuration? Also, what JDK is your IDE using in the project, and (to make sure) what version does java --version in the console output?

Answer (score 0):

***java.time.LocalTime***  appeared in Java8 so probably some of libraries you depends on is using Java8's classes (according to your stack trace this is Hibernate)

Comment: What was strange for me is that I do not receive this error while running the main class in IntelliJ, only when I execute the shaded jar.

Comment: Idea sometimes uses not actual classpath, I think that if you will reimport your project from scratch will be able to reproduce this.

Comment: After looking at your stacktrace more carefully, I would say that one if your classes (Hibernate Entities) implements some interface which uses java.time.* package in someway

Comment: Thanks, I will try to go in this direction and try to fix the problem. 
I'm using org.threeten.bp. I did a search through projects and libraries and Spring is the only place where java.time.* package is used.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a dependency on [`java.lang.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), which was introduced in Java 8.

Since you are using Java 7, you get a `ClassNotFoundException`. Either switch to Java 8 or replace the library that introduces the dependency.

Comment: What was strange for me is that I do not receive this error while running the main class (specified as main class for the shaded jar) in IntelliJ, only when I execute the shaded jar.